# Image slider doesn't work perfectly with the conflicts between bootstrap stackpath and maxcdn

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, slider

Image slider doesn't work for my website.

Here I am using for bootstrap

> https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css

And my images are coming under one after one.

But if I use

> https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css

then the image slider works fine. But my website other layout changed.

My HTML code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Carousel Example</h2>  
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="image/Banner_01.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="image/Banner_02.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="image/Banner_03.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

So what should I do now?

Comment: check the html structure because you are usign totally 2 different versions of bootstrap 4.2.1 and 3.4.0

Comment: Can we see your HTML? Also, you shouldn't include 2 versions of Bootstrap in one project

Comment: I have updated my post.Please check.

Comment: `carousel-item` in your html its item  `<div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>`

Comment: @ Vitorino fernandes...yours one is correct...Please answer the question according to stackoverflow rules. I will accept the answer